I can't compile project because of NETSDK1045 error
I never had this one before, have to say that i tried every guide uploaded to internet i could find.
Just to mention: i got every version of .net starting from 7.0
What can be this issue and how do i fix it ?
So, i thought about digging into PowerToys project (if it even matters). And i stumbled on this error, here's how i get it:

Fork project

Copy it to local machine

Follow contributors guidelines

Get this by attempting to compile: 'The current .NET SDK does not support the .NET 8.0 target. Select .NET 7.0 or earlier, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0.'



What version of Visual studio are you using?

Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you have installed .Net 8 SDK locally? Try to run command dotnet --info in your command line, it will show the list of available .net components.

I am so sorry i can't say my exact VS version for now, but i downloaded it last year.

Yes, i tried running dotnet --info command and it shows these: 7.0 8.0 and next one ( 8.0.23) if I'm not mistaken

When last year you have downloaded it?

I mean 2023, but i can't say exact date and at the same time i can't check it because I'm out of town

@TheCross Concrete date is not needed but approximate month of 2023 will do.

If you are working in free version from home, then install VS 2022 >=17.8 . According to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-8/

So i looked through whole bunch of media and latest screenshot of evidence i could find was on 1st of may

@TheCross have you checked the VS version? Is the issue fixed?

I am so sorry i can't say my exact VS version for now, but i downloaded it last year.
It is highly likely that you have an outdated VS version, update it. From the .NET 8 Release Notes: Visual Studio Compatibility:

You need Visual Studio 17.8 or later to use .NET 8.0 on Windows.


Thanks, will consider and try out as soon as i get to pc
